# PKI client behavior when delta CRL has expired

Tags: certificate, pki, ca

I have an internal Windows Server 2012 Enterprise Root CA and a couple of CDPs. I am trying to ensure a .NET client application running on Windows Server 2012 does not fail when it builds a certificate chain because the CRL and Delta CRL files it uses as part of the process have expired.

So far it seems like a possible solution would be to have overlapping CRLs being issued, to extend the time during which a failure preventing Base CRL publishing can kill an app depending on them (still looking for detailed/non-theoretical explanation on how exactly that is done, if you have examples, please let me know)

Another possible solution (or even in combination with overlapping CAs) would be to have a long CRL publication interval (e.g. 2 weeks) and a short Delta CRL interval (e.g. 1 hour). The question here is - what happens in scenario like this:

- A client has cached the Base and Delta CRLs
- For one reason or another the Delta CRL cannot be published to the CDPs for, let's say 6 hours - way past the validity of the Delta CRL, but (in most cases) before the Base CRL has expired

After an hour or so (providing the Delta CRL publishes every hour) the last successfully published Delta CRL would have expired, so the only valid one (for some time) would be the Base CRL. Would the client then continue processing since it has cached the Base CRL? Or would it fail? The closest explanation I have found is from [this old article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4954.windows-xp-certificate-status-and-revocation-checking.aspx#Delta_CRL_Processing): "*If a valid base CRL exists and is available, but no delta or time valid delta is available, the certificate chaining engine returns a warning that no delta CRL is available*". It seems the client should continue processing and not throw exception and that makes sense, but this is a very old article and I would feel more comfortable with something more up-to-date... :)

So, bottom line, does the above article still hold for modern systems? And if you have any detailed info on how to setup Overlapping CRL publishing on a Windows Server 2012 Enterprise CA, please share... :)

Thanks!

Comment: This [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc700843.aspx#XSLTsection127121120120) has very similar content to the one I linked above, but has some extra information confirming the behavior would be a 'warning' returned to the client by the Crypto chaining engine, rather than an error, when a Delta CRL is stale. See the "How Delta CRLs Work" and "Client Processing" sections. If someone has experience with and can confirm this, it would be great. Also if you have any detailed info on the overlapping, that would also be nice... I will post any updates as I find dig through the net.

Comment: OK, so it turns out my .NET app throws an exception if either the Base or Delta CRLs are missing or expired, even though the references I have seen (above) so far call missing/expired Delta CRL a 'warning' condition. And as far as the overlapping CRLs, it looks like it was a lot simpler than I originally thought - all I had to do is set the CRLOverlapPeriod and CRLDeltaOverlapPeriod registry keys to some N (non-0) value (smaller than the original publish frequency) and that in effect makes the CA publish a new CRL that much time sooner, hence the overlap... I guess I was overthinking it... :)